# Avoiding a quad join while finding all users that match a set of votes on an item

Tags: database, postgresql, group-by, relational-division

Let's say the following tables exist:

a `user` table with `user_id`

an `item` table with `item_id`

and a `vote` table with `user_id, item_id, value`

where `value` can be the integers 0 through 3. Users can vote on items.

I am looking for a way to perform a query such that I can find all users that have voted the same as an input user with a set of specified items and corresponding vote values.

For example, say I send a request to the app server with the following information:

```
user_id: 5
votes: [
  { item_id: 7, vote_value: 0 }, 
  { item_id: 3, vote_value: 3 }, 
  { item_id: 5, vote_value: 1 }, 
  { item_id: 41, vote_value: 3 }, 
  { item_id: 23, vote_value: 2 }
]
```

I would like to then return all the users that at least share these results (that is, all other users that voted 0 on item 7, voted 3 on item 3, voted 1 on item 5, voted 3 on item 41, and voted 2 on item 23). They can have more votes and other votes on other items, but at least those must match. Also, five voted items passed in is just an example. There are an arbitrary amount.

The only solution I have come up with so far involves a quad join and having a column for all 0 votes, all 1 votes, all 2 votes, and all 3 votes for each user, and then returning that entire dataset to the app-server to perform calculations there to find matches. But I was hoping there is a better, more performant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM votes
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (7, 0)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (3, 3)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (5, 1)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (41, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (23, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5764b/4)

The `HAVING` clause can also be expressed in the following manner

```
...
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (7, 0)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     + MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (3, 3)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (5, 1)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (41, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN (item_id, value) = (23, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 5
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5764b/7)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Unfortunately five items was just an example. There's an arbitrary amount passed in (so there could be anything from 0 to 100+ items to match on). I'll edit my post to clarify this.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, this may work. I could just dynamically build the query in my app server to include as many of those clauses as necessary. Hmm..

Comment: Exactly. You need to build the query dynamically.

Comment: In that case this may be perfect. I'm going to mess around with it to try better understand and integrate it. If all goes well I'll accept this tomorrow. Thanks.